# How to use doubles as keys in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, key, double

I have a csv data file that represent the trajectory of a body. The format is t, x, y, x. I want to store the history of that particle in a sort of HashMap in order to easily access the coordinates at a given time without read the file every time. My fear is that keys and values are objects, not primitives types. So, is a good idea to do something like this? For example I suppose that to fill the HashMap the Doubles have to be globally defined so that their address is well-defined for successive access... Right?

Comment: yes u can use Double as key...

Comment: You can always use Double as key. However, there might be issues of precision. What if you have a key with value 0.00001 in your map and you want to know if the key 0.000099 is present?

Comment: generally time is expressed with a long value. Since you interested in looking up coordinates by time, your key would be a Long, not a Double

Comment: You need more detail in your question (what's in the map?) if you use BigDecimal instead of double you'll not have the prescision issues. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: @tom My problem is not precision. I will implement a method that search the nearest time to the time requested...

Comment: @tom Excuse me, precision is a problem... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps, except identity maps like `IdentityHashMap`, use the `equals()` method to check for key equality.

So, you can use different instances as long as the are "equal" as defined by the semantics of the `equals()` method (and for hash maps as long as the `hashcode` method is coherent with `equals`) .. and Double respect both these requirements, so `Double` is ok.

However, a double number is subject to loss of precision, so if you use doubles obtained by some sort of computation, they can differ in decimals (like 8.999999 and 9, just to make you understand), and this can make the map not work properly.

Comment: Thank you! What about scope problem? If I fill the map in a while loop and the Doubles are created within the loop when the program exit the while it destroy the objects because they go out of scope, right?

Comment: If they are used as key in the map, the map will have a reference to them, so as long as the map does not go out of scope, even if you exit the loop you will not loose them .. if this is what you're asking.